# How make a value being changed as long as a button is being pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, button, long-integer

I have an initial value `CamTimeObsVar = 50` and I want make it reducing as long as button <kbd>btnCamTimeL</kbd> is being pressed. When I release the button to stop reducing. I tried the following code but the variable reduced only once. Is it possible to control the changing speed? I tried `sleep(0.1)` but it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x480')
Pressed = False

def CamTimeObsVarL(event):
    global CamTimeObsVar
    
    print("Button is pressed")
    CamTimeObsVar = CamTimeObsVar - 1
    lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
    sleep(0.1)
    

def Stop(event):
    global Pressed
    print("Stopping")
    Pressed = False

myFrame = Frame(root, width = 800, height=480)
CamTimeObsVar = 100
lblCamTime = Label(root)
lblCamTime.place(x=650, y=50)
lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
btnCamTimeL = Button(root, text ='L', width=1, height=1, bg='red')
btnCamTimeL.place(x=620, y=50)

btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',CamTimeObsVarL)
btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',Stop)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it is to bind both `ButtonPress` event and `ButtonRelease` events to the same event handler and use a check like `stop`. This stop would be `False` initially and will become `True` only if the `event.type==5`, that is mouse release event.

```py
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x480')
stop = False

def CamTimeObsVarL(event=None):
    global CamTimeObsVar, stop

    if event and int(event.type) == 4:
        stop = False

    if event and int(event.type) == 5:
        print('stopping')
        stop = True
    
    if stop==False:
        CamTimeObsVar = CamTimeObsVar - 1
        lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
        print("Button is pressed")
        a = root.after(100, CamTimeObsVarL)

myFrame = Frame(root, width = 800, height=480)
CamTimeObsVar = 100
lblCamTime = Label(root)
lblCamTime.place(x=650, y=50)
lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
btnCamTimeL = Button(root, text ='L', width=1, height=1, bg='red')
btnCamTimeL.place(x=620, y=50)

btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',CamTimeObsVarL)
btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',CamTimeObsVarL, '+')

root.mainloop()
```

Or you could also bind Release event and press event to different handlers as shown below.

```
def CamTimeObsVarL(event=None):
    global CamTimeObsVar, stop

    if event and int(event.type) == 4:
        stop = False
    
    if stop==False:
        CamTimeObsVar = CamTimeObsVar - 1
        lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
        print("Button is pressed")
        a = root.after(100, CamTimeObsVarL)

def end(event):
    global stop
    stop = True


btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',CamTimeObsVarL)
btnCamTimeL.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start a periodically update using `after()` when the button is pressed, then cancel the `after()` task when the button is released:

```py
def CamTimeObsVarL(event=None):
    global after_id, CamTimeObsVar
    print("Button is pressed")
    if CamTimeObsVar > 0:
        CamTimeObsVar -= 1
        lblCamTime['text'] = str(CamTimeObsVar) + ' sec'
        after_id = lblCamTime.after(100, CamTimeObsVarL) # update again 0.1 second later

def Stop(event):
    global after_id
    print("Stopping")
    if after_id:
        lblCamTime.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None
```

Comment: @Psiloritis If it solves your question, you are appreciated to accept it as an answer by clicking the `tick` beside the answer.